# A word meaning ‘enacted as law, but not yet implemented as social practise’

Tags: single-word-requests, research

I'm trying to recall a word I saw in the [Dictionary.com word of the day](http://www.dictionary.com/wordoftheday/) a few months back that meant something like a protection or ideal or a right that had been enacted merely as a law without having yet been assimilated into the ordinary practise of society.
Can anyone help me remember this word?

Comment: Not quite, no. The word I am looking for had the crucial and specific sense of there being a difference or discord or cleavage between the law and social practise.

Comment: There is the idiomatic phrase "a law honored more in the breach than in the observance".

Comment: Interesting. Though I do seem to recall there being a single word that captured the sense I'm alluding to!

Comment: I believe the 1558 Act of Uniformity in England, specifies *inter alia* that anyone not attending, weekly, a church where prayers are read from the Book of Common Prayer, is subject to a fine of 12 pence. I believe it remains on the statute book, though what would happen if anyone tried to enforce it in this day and age one dares not even contemplate. Is that the sort of thing you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, I think it would apply there. Yours is a good example of the older law becoming obsolete, not following societal attitudes. What I had in mind was the time period before societal attitude changed to accept a new law, e.g., people's acceptance of interracial marriages after the passage of antimiscegenation laws.

Comment: So are you asking about a permissive law which people haven't taken advantage of yet (say, being allowed to insult the first person you meet each day, which people think is just silly or could lead to problems) or a compulsive law which people don't follow because they don't see the point, even though they suffer the consequences (like wearing seat belts or not drinking and driving)? Or does that distinction not matter?

Comment: "avant-garde" laws ?

Comment: @Andrew-Leach I do not think the word specified the difference. I'm almost certain it was "de jure" as suggested by k1eran below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it is a *de jure* but not *de facto* law ...

> [...] ***De facto*** means a state of affairs that is true in fact, but that is not officially sanctioned. In contrast, ***de jure*** means a state of affairs that is in accordance with law (i.e. that is officially sanctioned). Most commonly, these phrases are used to describe the source of a business or governmental leader’s authority, but they apply to a wide variety of situations.  [...]
>   — https://onlinelaw.wustl.edu/blog/legal-english-de-factode-jure/

For example:

> ***De jure*** Segregation refers to intentional actions by the state to enforce racial segregation. The Jim Crow Laws of the southern states, which endured until the 1960s, are examples of ***de jure*** segregation. In contrast, ***de facto*** racial segregation, which occurred in other states, was accomplished by factors apart from conscious government activity.
>   — [West's Encyclopedia of American Law](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/de+jure)